# Visual Studio 2013 Compiler Warnings not Showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings

I installed Visual Studio 2013 last night and I'm noticing that it's not showing any warnings at all. Specifically, I want it to highlight unused local variables, private methods and the like. Is there a setting somewhere in Visual Studio that I need to enable?

Comment: Nope, the compiler should just show them. Is this on an existing project? Can you re-create this with a new project?

Comment: Unused private methods don't normally generate warnings at the C# compiler level. Something like R# can warn about it, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Are you thinking about Code Analysis instead of Compiler Warnings?

Comment: This is for VS 2010 but see if it helps. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/772484a2-5ae7-4efb-a732-cae75af1c7a8/vs2010-does-not-show-warnning-for-unused-local-variables-in-some-projects?forum=vsdebug

Comment: CA warnings used to show in the same place as Compiler Warnings.  By default they don't anymore.  There's a way to get them back, but I always forget when setting up a new dev. box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the solution by coincidence.


- Right click on your project a select "Properties".

- Go to the "Code Analysis" tab on the left.

- Change the Rule Set to "Microsft All Rules".


I had it set to "Microsft Managed Recommended Rules" by default, which did not even show warning for straight forward things like unused local variables. I selected "Microsoft All Rules" for a more granular set of warnings.