# Visual Studio 2013 not displaying unreferenced variable warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings

I am building in Visual Studio 2013, and if I add unreferenced variables to functions, the compiler does not throw warnings about them.  I tried enabling code analysis, per this thread:
[Visual Studio 2013 Compiler Warnings not Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874371/visual-studio-2013-compiler-warnings-not-showing)
but that still did not fix my issue.  Some additional information:

- I have the warning level set to 3 (/W3), am treating warning as errors (/WX), and am in a debug build with no optimization enabled.
- My full command line from Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line is:
  /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"generated\debug\intermediate\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "GLEW_STATIC" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MTd /Fa"generated\debug\intermediate\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"generated\debug\intermediate\" /Fp"generated\debug\intermediate\blahDebug.pch"
- I'm iterating on a function that I'm constantly debugging, stepping through the code, etc. -- so I know the code is being run.  But if I toss "int blah = 1;" in the function and recompile, no warnings are generated.

Example code:

```
bool MyClass::doSomething(int someParameter)
{
    int blah = 1;
    // run the normal function logic here
    // 'someParameter' is referenced, but 'blah' never is.
    // when i compile, i receive no warning that 'blah' is unreferenced.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?  There's a difference between [unreferenced local variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c733d5h9.aspx), and [unreferenced parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26kb9fy0.aspx).  The former is a level 3 warning, but the latter is level 4.  *Please post code that demonstrates your problem*.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan.  I added some example code.  I'm interested in the unreferenced local variables (C4101).  I tried adding explicit calls to: #pragma warning(default : 4101) with various warning levels as well, but that made no difference.

Comment: I wonder if the assignment in the declaration counts as "referencing" the variable.  If you change the line to `int blah;` does it throw the error?  Unfortunately I don't have a VS install available right now.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct!  If I remove the assignment and leave `int blah;` then the warning is thrown.  I'm not sure if that is the intended behavior or not.  It seems a little crazy to me that it can't detect the lack of use despite initialization, though the example on MSDN doesn't have initialization either: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c733d5h9(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: It is intentional because initialization is not assignment so you are creating blah with an int constructor, then you are using blah in the operator= call. Not what you may be thinking which is just creating blah. Use `int blah{1};` and see if that makes a difference. I can't remember if C++ has a `int blah(1);` but that's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, @user2913685.  Both `int blah(1);` and `int blah{1};` compile without throwing the warning, so they appear to be treated the same as assignment.

Comment: As @RyanBemrose said, Compile it with /Wall or /W4 for warnings. /W3 is'nt gonna cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, the statement `int blah = 1;` both declares the variable and assigns to it.  Visual Studio counts this assignment as a "reference" of the variable, thus avoiding the [C4101 unreferenced local variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c733d5h9.aspx) error that you are expecting.

*To locate and remove variables which are initialized but never used, you can use a static analysis tool such as Prefast or CppCheck.  There is a list of such tools [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97454/c-static-code-analysis-tool-on-windows), though it may be out of date.*

Note that the compiler can flag unused **parameters**, even if they are initialized with a default parameter. If you use warning level 4 via `/W4` or `/Wall`, then an unused parameter will cause a [C4100 unreferenced parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26kb9fy0.aspx) warning.  It is a very good idea to always build at `/W4` or `/Wall`, rather than the default `/W3`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan Bemrose outlined, static code analysis tools can be used to detect unused resources from source code.

Take a look at following function:

```
bool foo(int unusedParameter)
{
  int unusedVariable = 1;
  return true;
}
```

It contains two unused resources, an unused parameter and and unused but initialized local variable. Cppcheck can assist you to detect unused local variables, by using the following command:

```
$ cppcheck --enable=all test.cpp 
  Checking test.cpp...
  [test.cpp:3]: (style) Variable 'unusedVariable' is assigned a value that is never used.
```

Currently it does not detect unused parameters.