# Visual Studio Mac highlight warnings in code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac, stylecop

In Visual Studio for Windows, warnings are underlined in green. I am trying to get the same result in Visual Studio Mac, but it only highlights errors (in red). In the error pad (View -> Pads -> Errors) there are many warnings, but they are not highlighted in the code.

I'm using stylecop so warnings are a very frequent thing. But it is not really workable if they're not highlighted in my code.

For VS (windows) this was [configurable in the Code Analyzer tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874371/visual-studio-2013-compiler-warnings-not-showing). This has been replaced I believe by Roselyn editorconfigs, but with this I have been unable to figure out how to configure warning highlighting in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in the latest version of Visual Studio for mac (checked with 8.3.4)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my solutions is exactly what are you looking for, but I use 2 extensions for highlight errors and warnings:

**Error Lens** (usernamehw.errorlens) for highlight the entire line and show on real time the error diagnostic

**Error Gutters** (igorsbitnev.error-gutters) for put error icons next of line number

Both look like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm going to try it out and see if it serves as a work-around. I will let you know! Cheers